# Power Query : Data Source Connection issue

Tags: excel, datasource, powerquery

I am using Power Query for Excel and I am trying to connect MySQL database which is hosted on AWS. While trying to connect, I am getting an ERROR in query editor saying ***"DataSource.Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."***

My Excel and Power Query both has 32-bit version.

Is there any issue in setting up Data Source?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem. 64 bit Excel and latest version of PowerQuery. The cause of mine was that I had copied and pasted the output of a PowerQuery query into a new Excel sheet. This created a shadow second data connection invisible to the PowerQuery pane.

To fix it I had to go to the Data ribbon > click Connections, highlight the second query (named [YourQueryName]1) and click the Remove button. After that things went back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to Send-A-Frown from inside Power Query to get in direct contact with the developers.

Please check that you have the latest version of Power Query installed. It might help to upgrade MySQL drivers too.